# Is there any sense to train deep conv net from the scratch after dataset changes?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convergence

I train deep conv model called resnet50 as the object detector. Time to time I make some changes in dataset or data augmentation. I usually use my last checkpoint to continue training on whole changed dataset. But Is there any sense for me to train model from the scratch? Another words will the error surface change dramatically and get totally different global minimum after train dataset changes so train from scratch will be much better thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't train from scratch if you can avoid it. First, deep nets never converge on the global minimum during training, so there's no point in worrying about that. Second, nets trained on an image classification task often have weights that prove useful for initializing networks for entirely different tasks / datasets, so the transferability of network weights has long been confirmed.